# CircleCI with Postgres - cannot connect

Tags: postgresql, docker, circleci

In my Circle build, I'm trying to use a Postgres container for testing. The test DB will be created automatically, but Python's not finding the DB. Here's my `config.yml`:

```
version: 2.1
​
orbs:
  python: circleci/python@0.2.1
​
jobs:
  build:
    executor: python/default
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.8.0
        environment:
          - ENV: CIRCLE
      - image: circleci/postgres:9.6
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: circleci
          POSTGRES_DB: circle_test
          POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    steps:
      - checkout
      - python/load-cache
      - run:
          command: |
            python3 -m venv venv
            . venv/bin/activate
            pip3 install -r requirements.txt
      - python/save-cache
      - run:
          name: Running tests
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            python3 ./api/manage.py test
      - store_artifacts:
          path: test-reports/
          destination: python_app
​
workflows:
  main:
    jobs:
      - build
```

It seems like everything's fine until the tests start:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

There's no such folder:

```
ls -a /var/run/
.  ..  exim4  lock  utmp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes in the `PGHOST` and `DATABASE_URL` config solved it:

```
 jobs:
  build:
    executor: python/default
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.8.0
        environment:
          ENV: CIRCLE
          DATABASE_URL: postgresql://circleci@localhost/circle_test
      - image: circleci/postgres:9.6
        environment:
          PGHOST: localhost
          PGUSER: circleci
          POSTGRES_USER: circleci
          POSTGRES_DB: circle_test
          POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    steps:
      - checkout
      - python/load-cache
      - run:
          name: Wait for db to run
          command: dockerize -wait tcp://localhost:5432 -timeout 1m
      - run:
          command: |
            python3 -m venv venv
            . venv/bin/activate
            pip3 install -r requirements.txt
      - python/save-cache
      - run:
          name: Running tests
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            cat /etc/hosts
            python3 ./django/gbookapi/manage.py test gbook.tests
      - store_test_results:
          path: test-reports.xml
      - store_artifacts:
          path: test-reports/
          destination: python_app

workflows:
  main:
    jobs:
      - build
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like psycopg2 [defaults to using the UNIX socket](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect), so you'll need to specify the db host as `localhost` in your `connect()` call.

Also an aside, but it looks like you're specifying an additional but unneeded Python image. The executor for the job is already set to be `python/default` so it doesn't seem like the next image `circleci/python:3.8.0` is doing anything based on the config you've pasted in.

Comment: There's no `connect()` call, as Django is handling the setup of the connection